# GDB doesn't step in function outside one file

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb

I try to debug my program with `gdb` and the `step` function. 
Everything works fine as long as the functions are in the same file.

But if the function is outside, gdb will jump over it.

How can I solve that?

Note:

- I compiled with `-ggdb` options
- I'm using `GNU gdb Red Hat Linux (6.7-1rh)`
  (if that is possible, appeared in startfrequence of gdb)

Example:

```
#include "foo2.h"  // contains function foo2

void foo(void){ printf("hello"); }


void main (void){

  foo();    // debuggable -> jump into possible
  foo2();   // not debuggable 


}
```

Comment: What version of the `gcc` compiler are you using (current is 4.7)? What exact options are you giving to it? You could use `gcc -Wall -g3` perhaps with `-fno-inline`

Comment: You have a very old version of `gdb`; the latest one is 7.5

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch  linux-powerpc-gcc version 4.2.2

Comment: Both gcc 4.2 and gdb 6.7 are very old versions. You really should **upgrade your Linux system**. Notice that kernel folks, compiler folks, binutils folks, libc folks have made significant progress since your system installation (which happened several years ago).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When debugging the application with gdb, use si (stepi) instead of ni (nexti). si will step into other functions, ni stays within the current function. Check the documentation at http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html#Continuing-and-Stepping for more (^F for nexti or stepi).